# Stop multithreading in Excel from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, multithreading, slowdown

I am running into problems with the speed of my macros.  I already turn off calculations and turn them back on.  I turn off screen updating then turn it back on.  Simply put I have tried all the tricks to speed up the macro execution.  While executing, it shows thread calculation in the bottom right of the screen.  I would like to be able to turn multithreading off programmatically so I do not have to tell people to do it manually when I give them the file to us.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does turning multithreading off really speed things up? As far as I know, VBA does not natively support multithreading. It's only a thing for calculations. And I don't see why multithreading would be slower. What are you doing in your macro? There could be ways to optimize it.

Comment: Why don't you post one of your slow macros and see how slow it is after someone optimizes it?

Comment: Excel VBA is single threaded. Please could you update the question with the relevant code and a screenshot of this thread calculation. I think you are maybe referring to the calculated cells count?

Comment: I have never heard of multi-threading in Excel, or VBA, or anything related to either of those things. When workbooks grow really huge, or if you are doing lots of calculations, or you are using dynamic functions, or all of those things, things get really slow. Now may be a great time to start learning Python!!

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more research, I did find the answer.  Turning off events, screen updating and making calculations manual does not solve the problem.  But this does:

Application.MultiThreadedCalculation.Enabled = False

If you put this in your script you may see a significant improvement in performance.  I know I did!

Comment: This was acctually what was happening to me. I have processes that calculates several cells and macro runs combining several information. When I turn off multi threaded calculation, the process runs in 6 seconds. Otherwise, it runs for 67 seconds. I have absolute no idea why it happens. I just know that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

```
    Sub turnOffCalc()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

End Sub

Sub turnOnCalc()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```